# How to generate XML file using libxml2?

Tags: xsd, libxml2, xml

I have downloaded libxml2 from xmlsoft.org. I used this for parsing an xml file. Now I want to create my own xml file using the same libxml like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Powersettings>
<PowerScheme>Testing</PowerScheme>
<CPUSpeed>Adaptive</CPUSpeed>
<Screensaver>No</Screensaver>
<LockScreentime>0</LockScreentime>
<Shutdownflag>Yes</Shutdownflag>
<DownloadsFlag>No</DownloadsFlag>
<PPasswordprotected>No</PPasswordprotected>
<Appsensorname>(None)</Appsensorname>
</Powersettings>
```

I am using gcc compiler, C language to write program and whole data is in a Structure.
I'm looking for a Good tutorial or an example program to create xml document as above using libxml2.

Any help ?

Answer (score 4):

Based on http://xmlsoft.org/examples/testWriter.c  -- disclaimer: I have never used libxml2, haven't tested it, and there's no error detection:

```
xmlTextWriterPtr writer;
writer = xmlNewTextWriterFilename("test.xml", 0);
xmlTextWriterStartDocument(writer, NULL, "UTF-8", NULL);
xmlTextWriterStartElement(writer, "Powersettings");
xmlTextWriterWriteElement(writer, "PowerScheme", "Testing"); xmlTextWriterEndElement(writer);
xmlTextWriterWriteElement(writer, "CPUSpeed", "Adaptive"); xmlTextWriterEndElement(writer);
/* ... etc ... */
xmlTextWriterEndElement(writer);
xmlTextWriterEndDocument(writer);
xmlFreeTextWriter(writer);
```