# Write data into XML from DLL

Tags: xml, visual-c++, dll, file-handling

I am trying to iterate over a std::list and write data into xml from a thread in DLL. But my XML is not getting created if I dump more fields of object into XML. Below are the details of my class and the code I am using to write data into XML.

```
class MyClass{
private:
    BSTR member1;
    BSTR member2;
    BSTR member3;
    BSTR member4;
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
    BSTR getMember1()
    {
        return member1;
    }
    BSTR getMember2()
    {
        return member2;
    }
    BSTR getMember3()
    {
        return member3;
    }
    BSTR getMember4()
    {
        return member4;
    }
    //Corresponding setters are also present
};

std::list<MyClass> myList;
std::list<MyClass>::iterator iterator;

ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open("C:\\test.xml",ios::out);
outputFile << "<root>" << endl;
for(iterator=myList.begin();iterator != myList.end();++iterator)
{
     //Not working if more values are dumped
     USES_CONVERSION;
     outputFile << "<Object>" << endl;
     outputFile << "<Member1>" << W2A(CString((*iterator).getMember1())) << "</Member1>" << endl;
     outputFile << "<Member2>" << W2A(CString((*iterator).getMember2())) << "</Member2>" << endl;
     outputFile << "<Member3>" << W2A(CString((*iterator).getMember3())) << "</Member3>" << endl;
     outputFile << "<Member4>" << W2A(CString((*iterator).getMember4())) << "</Member4>" << endl;
     outputFile << "</Object>" << endl;
}
outputFile << "</root>";
outpuFile.close();
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: You should always use some well know XML library like libxml2,xmlite or MSXML6 instead of rendering text to XML

Comment: @rkosegi Thanks for the information. I will try to use them. Could you please point me to some good tutorials?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc507416%28v=vs.85%29.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743879/how-to-generate-xml-file-using-libxml2

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, It was because I am writing into file without checking whether the value is NULL.
For some objects all members were not populated.

```
 outputFile << "<Member3>" << W2A(CString((*iterator).getMember3())) << "</Member3>" << endl;
```

I should check whether **getMember3()** is giving any data or NULL before I write into file :).

/Hareesh